# Maintain the button state inside a custom cell loaded from xib

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cell loaded from  xib 
the cell has a button change it's image when touched down 
My problem is when I scroll the table up and down out side the view the button reload it's default image

this is my code

for the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifer=@"LabelCell";
    TestTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

   if (cell==nil) 
    {
       cell = [[TestTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) 
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[TestTableCell class]])
            {
                cell = (TestTableCell*)view;
            }
        }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    UIImage *cellbackground=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
    cell.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cellbackground];

   }
    return  cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store whether the image has been pressed in your data model. UITableView will reuse your cell for other rows while you scroll and everything inside the cell will be forgotten.

Comment: +1 Hey Ben, second time within minutes that you came up with an answer while I was typing in the same ...

Comment: You mean like a global array that I have to check it when ever the cellForRowAtIndexPath called

Comment: @Mohammed, an array that's owned by the viewcontroller containing the UITableView yes. Please don't use a global ;-)

Comment: The cell contain button which has an event in the cell.m file how can I access the array owned by the viewcontroller containing the UITableview can you provide a simple code for your suggestion

Comment: @Mohammed The answer is not to do it that way around. Instead, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, pass the data INTO to the cell by setting a property. e.g. [cell setData:[NSArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]. Then when the button is pressed you can access the data from the viewController, albeit indirectly.